# Frequency distribution of hierarchical strings

Tags: algorithm

I have about 10K hierarchical strings like this. They can have up to 10-12 levels of hierarchy (/).

`/a/b/c 
 /a/b/d 
 /e/b/c`

For each level i, I would like to calculate the distribution of the hierarchy path up to level i. So for the above case, it would be like this:

```
level 0:
/a  0.67
/e  0.33

level 1:
/a/b 0.67
/e/b 0.33

level 2:
/a/b/c 0.33
/a/b/d 0.33
/e/b/c 0.33
```

How can I do this efficiently for 10K strings with max of 10-12 levels. This must be a very common string manipulation algorithm for this, but I'm forgetting the correct name. Thanks.

Comment: You can use any parsing library or tool (e.g. sed if this in in a raw text file, or regular expression libraries) to extract your desired data.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary (map) that's indexed by string name, and contains a count.

For each string, split it on the path separator '/'. Then, starting with a blank string, add each segment to the string and increment the count in the map. Looks like this:

```
for each path string
    split path into segments
    newPath = ''
    for each segment
        add to newpath
        increment count of newpath occurrences in dictionary
    end
end
```

When that's done, you have a list of sub-paths and numbers. In your example, you'd have:

```
a,2
a/b,2
a/b/c,1
a/b/d,1
e,1
e/b,1
e/c,1
```

Now all you have to do is go through the map and divide the count by the total number of path strings:

```
for each item in dictionary
    output key, count/string_count
```

In this case, string_count is 3 because that was the original number of strings you supplied.

I'd be really surprised if it took more than a second to process all 10K strings with at most 12 levels of hierarchy.